# Using io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni to create a response object

Tags: rest, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

I am trying to learn using ReactiveMongoClient on a Quarkus framework.

I am partly successful with sending a response as Uni>

```
@GET
@Path("/unpaginated")
public Uni<List<Staff>> unpaginatedStaffList() {
    return staffService.getStaffResponse();
}
```

But when I try to get an object of some other class (StaffResponse) to include a Link object for pagination, I am not getting any Staff record.
(For now I have hardcoded Link for pagination )

```
@GET
@Path("/paginated")
public StaffResponse paginatedStaffList() {
    List<Link> links = LinkService.getLinks("/staff?page=2&limit=20", "next");
    Uni<List<Staff>> staff = (Uni<List<Staff>>) staffService.getStaffResponse();
    return new StaffResponse(links, staff);
}
```

"staff" is empty in the response.

MongoClient is returning list of Staff ok, looks like the Response object is not getting the list.
Tried reading SmallRye Mutiny documentations - could not work out.

Please help.

I have committed the code at: https://github.com/doepradhan/staffApi
and a sample json data file (https://github.com/doepradhan/staffApi/blob/master/sample-staff-data.json)

Thank you heaps for you kind help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't mix up two approaches. You need to use `Uni` as an output for the endpoint. That means that you need to convert both input sources into Uni, combine them, and map into `StaffResponse`.

1. Convert `LinkService` to return Uni(or use Uni.createFrom().item(links))
2. Change StaffResoponse to only use simple objects:

```java
public StaffResponse(List<Link> links, List<Staff> staff) {
        this.links = links;
        this.staff = staff;
    }
```

3. As said before, get two Uni sources and combine them together, you'll get `Uni<Tuple>`, map it then to `StaffResponse`:

```java
    @GET
    @Path("/paginated")
    public Uni<StaffResponse> paginatedStaffList() {
        final Uni<List<Link>> links =
                Uni.createFrom().item(LinkService.getLinks("/staff?page=2&limit=20", "next"));
        Uni<List<Staff>> staff = staffService.getStaffResponse();
        return staff.and(links).map(it -> new StaffResponse(it.getItem2(), it.getItem1()));
    }
```

I created a working PR [here](https://github.com/doepradhan/staffApi/pull/1/files)

Comment: Thanks Dmytro.
Worked exactly as expected.

Comment: This has to be the best answer I have ever seen